# Excel VBA for searching String within an Outlook Attachment, flagging email if match is found

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

Basically I have a list of 5000 strings populated in an Excel spreadsheet. I want VBA to go through the attachments in an Outlook Inbox and if it finds a string match, I want the particular email to be flagged. Here's the code I have so far

```
Sub attachsearch()
On Error GoTo bigerror
Dim ns As Namespace
Dim inbox As MAPIFolder
Dim subfolder As MAPIFolder
Dim item As Object
Dim atmt As Attachment
Dim filename As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim varresponse As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim workbk As Workbook
Dim SearchString As String
Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set subfolder = inbox.Folders("test")
Set workbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\John.Doe\Desktop\10 25 2016 Pricing Team Macro.xlsm")
i = 0
If subfolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
MsgBox "There are no emails to look at. Please stop wasting my time.", vbInformation, "Folder is Empty"
Exit Sub
End If
For Each item In subfolder.Items
For Each atmt In item.Attachments
For rwindex = 1 To 5000
SearchString = Workbooks("10 25 2016 Pricing Team Macro").Sheets("NDC Sort").Cells(rwindex, 1).Value
```

Below is the problem code, index proberty is not used correctly here, but I'm unsure what to use. I know that Microsoft indexes the words within the attachment because when I manually type in the search string in Outlook, it pulls up the email even though the string is only present within the attachment. So ultimately, my question is, how do I leverage that attachment index in VBA?

```
If atmt.Index Like "*" & Workbooks("10 25 2016 Pricing Team Macro").Sheets("NDC Sort").Cells(rwindex, 1).Value & "*" Then
i = i + 1
With item
    .FlagRequest = "Follow up"
    .Save
End With
End If
Next rwindex
Next atmt
Next item
If i > 0 Then
MsgBox "I found " & i & " attached files with a specific name."
Else
MsgBox "I didn't find any files"
End If
Set atmt = Nothing
Set item = Nothing
Set ns = Nothing
workbk.Close savechanges:=False
Exit Sub
bigerror:
MsgBox "something went wrong"
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you searching? String on Attachment Name or inside the attachment file?

Comment: Inside the attacment file

Comment: in order to search inside attachment, you will have to save it first, what type files are they? spreadsheet? word?

Comment: OK. I'm now writing it to run a different process for xls, pdf, and doc files. I'll post that code when I'm done since that may be the best answer. If anyone else has insight though i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution if you only need to search the contents PDFs, MSWord, and Excel. There's a different procedure for each. A caveat is that you need to have a version of Adobe that you pay for. This won't work on plain Adobe Reader. I've tested it a few times and it works, but it seems kind of chunky in some parts so I'm open to suggestions.

```
            Sub attachsearch()
            Dim ns As Namespace
            Dim inbox As MAPIFolder
            Dim subfolder As MAPIFolder
            Dim item As Object
            Dim atmt As Attachment
            Dim tempfilepath As String
            Dim tempfilename As String
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim workbk As Workbook
            Dim LastRow As Long
            Dim TextToFind  As String
            Dim Loc As Range
            Dim Sh As Worksheet
            Dim WS_Count As Integer
            Dim x As Integer
            Dim WS_Name As String

            Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
            Set inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
            Set subfolder = inbox.Folders("test")
            Set workbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\John.Doe\Desktop\10 25 2016 Pricing Team Macro.xlsx")
            LastRow = Workbooks("10 25 2016 Pricing Team Macro").Worksheets("NDC Sort").Cells(Worksheets("NDC Sort").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            i = 0
            If subfolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "There are no emails to look at. Please stop wasting my time.", vbInformation, "Folder is Empty"
            Exit Sub
            End If

            For Each item In subfolder.Items
            For Each atmt In item.Attachments
            If item.FlagStatus = Empty Then
                If Right(atmt.Filename, 4) Like "xl**" Or Right(atmt.Filename, 3) Like "xl*" Then
                    tempfilepath = "O:\aaaTEST\"
                    tempfilename = Format(item.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_") & item.SenderName & "_" & atmt.Filename
                    atmt.SaveAsFile tempfilepath & tempfilename
                    Workbooks.Open (tempfilepath & tempfilename)
                    Workbooks(tempfilename).Activate
                    WS_Count = Workbooks(tempfilename).Worksheets.Count
                    'Clearing any selections that may limit the search unintentionally
                    For x = 1 To WS_Count
                    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(x)
                    .Select
                    .Cells(1, 1).Select
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    End With
                    Next x
                For rwindex = 2 To LastRow
                    If item.FlagStatus = Empty Then
                    TextToFind = Workbooks("10 25 2016 Pricing Team Macro").Sheets("NDC Sort").Cells(rwindex, 1).Value
                        If TextToFind <> "" Then
                            Workbooks(tempfilename).Activate
                            For x = 1 To WS_Count
                            With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(x)
                                    .Select
                                    .UsedRange.Select
                                   Set Loc = .Cells.Find(TextToFind)
                            If item.FlagStatus = Empty Then
                                If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
                                 i = i + 1
                                 With item
                                .FlagRequest = "Follow up"
                                .Save
                                End With
                                End If
                            End If
                            Set Loc = Nothing
                            End With
                            Next x
                        End If
                     End If
                     Next rwindex
                     Workbooks(tempfilename).Close Savechanges:=False
                End If

            'PDF Check
                If Right(atmt.Filename, 3) = "pdf" Then
                    tempfilename = "O:\aaaTEST\" & _
                    Format(item.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_") & item.SenderName & "_" & atmt.Filename
                    atmt.SaveAsFile tempfilename
                    PDFPath = tempfilename

                Set App = CreateObject("AcroExch.App", "")

                Set AVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

                        If AVDoc.Open(PDFPath, "") = True Then
                          AVDoc.BringToFront
                          For rwindex = 2 To 3593
                            If item.FlagStatus = Empty Then
                            TextToFind = Workbooks("10 25 2016 Pricing Team Macro").Sheets("NDC Sort").Cells(rwindex, 1).Value
                                If AVDoc.FindText(TextToFind, False, True, False) = True Then
                                i = i + 1
                                With item
                                .FlagRequest = "Follow up"
                                .Save
                                End With
                                End If
                            AVDoc.Close True
                            App.Exit
                            End If
                        Next rwindex
                        End If
                End If

                'MSWord check
                If Right(atmt.Filename, 4) Like "doc*" Or Right(atmt.Filename, 3) Like "doc" Then
                    tempfilepath = "O:\aaaTEST\"
                    tempfilename = Format(item.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_") & item.SenderName & "_" & atmt.Filename
                    atmt.SaveAsFile tempfilepath & tempfilename
                    Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
                    wordapp.Documents.Open Filename:=tempfilepath & tempfilename
                    wordapp.Visible = True
                    For rwindex = 2 To 5
                        If item.FlagStatus = Empty Then
                        TextToFind = Workbooks("10 25 2016 Pricing Team Macro").Sheets("NDC Sort").Cells(rwindex, 1).Value
                            If TextToFind <> "" Then
                                With wordapp.ActiveDocument.Content.Find
                                .ClearFormatting
                                .Execute FindText:=TextToFind
                                If .Found = True Then
                                    i = i + 1
                                    With item
                                        .FlagRequest = "Follow up"
                                        .Save
                                    End With
                                End If
                                End With
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next rwindex
                wordapp.ActiveDocument.Close Savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
                wordapp.Quit Savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
                End If
            End If
            Next atmt
            Next item
            Workbooks("10 25 2016 Pricing Team Macro").Close Savechanges:=False

            If i > 0 Then
            MsgBox "I found " & i & " attached files with a specific name."
            Else
            MsgBox "I didn't find any files"
            End If
            Set atmt = Nothing
            Set item = Nothing
            Set ns = Nothing
            Exit Sub

            End Sub
```